# What is the best practice when using with context.WithTimeout() in Go?

Tags: go

I want to use `context.WithTimeout()` to handle a use case that I make an external request, and if the response of the request is too long, it will return an error.

I have implemented the pseudo code like the playground link attached below:
2 solution:

- main -> not expected
- main_1 -> expected

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// I just dummy sleep in this func to produce use case this func
// need 10s to process and handle logic. 
// And this assume will be out of timeOut expect (5s)
func makeHTTPRequest(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(10) * time.Second)
    return "abc", nil
}

// In main Func, I will set timeout is 5 second. 
func main() {
    var strCh = make(chan string, 1)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Duration(5)*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    fmt.Print("Begin make request\n")
    abc, err := makeHTTPRequest(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("Return error\n")
        return
    }

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Printf("Return ctx error: %s\n", ctx.Err())
        return
    case strCh <- abc:
        fmt.Print("Return response\n")
        return
    }
}

func main_1() {
    var strCh = make(chan string, 1)
    var errCh = make(chan error, 1)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Duration(5)*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    go func() {
        fmt.Print("Begin make request\n")
        abc, err := makeHTTPRequest(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Print("Return error\n")
            errCh <- err
            return
        }
        strCh <- abc

    }()
    select {
    case err := <-errCh:
        fmt.Printf("Return error: %s\n", err.Error())
        return
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Printf("Return ctx error: %s\n", ctx.Err())
        return
    case str := <-strCh:
        fmt.Printf("Return response: %s\n", str)
        return
    }
}
```

However, if with the `main()` function then it doesn't work as expected.
But if with the second `main_1()` implementation using goroutine then maybe the new `context.WithTimeout()` works as expected.

Can you help me to answer this problem?

https://play.golang.org/p/kZdlm_Tvljy

Comment: This is basically nonsense. Your makeHttpRequest function should monitor the ctx parameter and return early if ctx is done. Actually that is what net/http does with Requests that have a context. You code just sleeps and doesn't react to ctx expiring. This design failure in makeHttpRequest forces the calling code to do mumbo jumbo without real benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to handle context in your `makeHTTPRequest()` function, so you can use it as a synchronous function in `main()`.

https://play.golang.org/p/Bhl4qprIBgH

```golang
func makeHTTPRequest(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
    ch := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        select {
        case ch <- "abc":
        default:
            // When context deadline exceeded, there is no receiver
            // This case will prevent goroutine blocking forever
            return
        }
    }()

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return "", ctx.Err()
    case result := <-ch:
        return result, nil
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    fmt.Printf("[%v] Begin make request \n", time.Now())
    abc, err := makeHTTPRequest(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("[%v] Return error: %v \n", time.Now(), err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("[%v] %s", time.Now(), abc)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right. There are two questiones.

1. You want to know why main() function not work?
2. What's the best practice?

#### Q1

`main()` blocked at makeHTTPRequest, and during that time, context had timeout. So, not work as expected.

#### Q2

This [example](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithTimeout) can answer you. In `main_1()` , your code is already best practice.

Comment: Oh yes. My bad. 
Just like you said. I have 2 issues that need attention. Thank you so much.